# Dynamically created form is not being recognized by validation script

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

Having some trouble with getting a form to validate. I have part of an application with address fields that need to be filled out. There is an option to add additional address information. However after the address fields appear and the submit button is clicked, if the added fields are empty they will not validate. Can someone assist me with a solution here. I have also provided some code below.

I'm wondering if it is because the forms are being added with javascript.

Here is my javascript:

```
//validate form

var fields = [
    {
        selector: $('.not-empty'),
        validations: [ isNotEmpty]
    },
    {
        selector: $('.email'),
        validations: [ isNotEmpty, isEmail]
    },
    {
        selector: $('.number'),
        validations: [ isNotEmpty, isNumber]
    },
    {
        selector: $('.number-noreq'),
        validations: [isNumber]
    }
];
$(document.ready(function(){
    $('#job-application-form').on('click', 'button[type=submit]', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        validate();
    });

    $('#add_address').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.address-form').clone().removeClass('address-form').insertAfter('.address-form');
    });
});
function validate(){
    $('.form-control').closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    var i = 0, k = 0, z = 0, j = fields.length, item, selector, fn, info;
    for(; i < j; i++){
        item = fields[i];
        for(k = 0; k < item.validations.length; k++){
            fn = item.validations[k];
            for( z = 0; z < item.selector.length; z++){
                selector = $(item.selector[z]);
                info = selector.closest('.form-group');
                if(info)
                    info[fn(selector.val()) ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']('has-error');
            }
        }
    }
}


//validation functions
function isNotEmpty(value){
    return value && $.trim(value).length > 0;
}
function isEmail(value){
    return /^([^@\s\t\n]+\@[\w\d]+\.[\w]{2,3}(\.[\w]{2})?)$/.test(value);
}

function isNumber(value){
    return /^\d+$/.test(value);   
}
```

Here is the form

```
<span id='address_records' class='app-section'>
                <span class='address-form'>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-md-4'>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label>Current Address</label>
                                <input type='text' class='form-control not-empty' name='address[]'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-md-4'>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <input type='text' class='form-control' name='address2[]'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-md-2'>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label>City</label>
                                <input type='text' class='form-control not-empty' name='city[]'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-md-2 col-md-offset-1'>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label>State</label>
                                <select class='form-control not-empty' name='state[]'>
                                    <? include 'inc/state_list_options.php';?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-md-2 col-md-offset-1'>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label>Zip</label>
                                <input type='text' class='form-control not-empty' name='zip[]' maxlength='5'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-md-2'>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label>From</label>
                                <div class='input-group'>
                                    <input type='text' class='form-control half-input not-empty' name='addr_from_month[]'>
                                    <input type='text' class='form-control half-input not-empty' name='addr_from_year[]'>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-md-2 col-md-offset-1'>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label>To</label>
                                <div class='input-group'>
                                    <input type='text' class='form-control half-input not-empty' name='addr_to_month[]'>
                                    <input type='text' class='form-control half-input not-empty' name='addr_to_year[]'>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </span>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-12'>
                        <div class='form-group'>
                            <a href="" id="add_address">Add Another Address</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (think) you need to use .on() within the scope of the elements which are changing. I dont see your actual submit button in your sample code so this is just an example

```
$('#address_records').on('click','button[type=submit]',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    validate();
});
```

additionally you need to move the var fields = [] declaration within the validate() function.  Currently you are defining the fields to contain the DOM elements matching the selectors at page load time.  The cloned elements do not exist at that point.  They do exist when the validate function is run however, so you want to use your selector at that point, then run the validation on all of the discovered elements.

Comment: my submit button function is most definitely in there. It's right after the fields array

Comment: Sorry, i do not see any <button> tags in your sample form at all :(
It looks like you edited your sample code though to switch the .on() to an <a> tag instead of a button, but did you try my suggestion to use the entire form (or whatever your parent element of the form fields is) rather than your submit element?

Comment: oh sorry I didn't put the section of the form in there with the submit button, the application form is quite large actually. Yes I tried your example, no dice, any other suggestions?

Comment: did you update your question with the one you tried ? I still see two attempts at capturing form submission and they both appear to be using .on() against the submit element rather than the container of the form. For example, all fields appear to be under this container, so attach the event here
<span id='address_records'>

Comment: Okay, can you pull your selectors within the validation function ?  If they are declared outside, i am wondering if they are assigned before the new address fields are created. If you create the selectors within the validation function however, maybe it will work ?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because they aren't being recognized as an object within the DOM

Comment: That is why i am wondering if you are declaring var fields = [] too early, as the selectors are collecting the DOM elements that exist at that time, not the dom elements that exist at the time of form submission

Comment: no I don't think that has anything to do with it, I looked into that already

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62428/discussion-between-mark-hill-and-lonewolf217).

Answer (score 0):

I think no need jquery for form validation. Reason you using HTML5  and Bootstrap3.
Here is form validation using HTML5 structure:

```
<input type="text" class="" placeholder="" required="required" /> /* Only Text */
<input type="email" class="" placeholder="" required="required" /> /* Only email */
<input type="text" class="" placeholder="Zip Code" required="required" pattern="[0-9]{5}" /> /* Only Zip code US */
<input type="text" class="" placeholder="Telephone" required="required" pattern="[0-9]{11}" /> /* Only Telephone */
type="button"
type="checkbox"
type="color"
type="date"
type="datetime"
type="datetime-local"
type="file"
type="hidden"
type="image"
type="month"
type="number"
type="password"
type="radio"
type="reset"
type="search"
type="submit"
type="tel"
type="time"
type="url"
type="week"
            required="required"
            readonly="readonly"
```

Comment: Browser support isn't that great for HTML5 validation.  Not supported before IE10 and limited support in Safari / mobile http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/